# Black Screen on AnyDesk Connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, android, remote-access, tablet

I am using AnyDesk to mirror a Windows 7 laptop screen onto an Android Tablet.  Until recently, everything was fine, but one day, and every time since, I connected as usual but could only see a black screen.  I can still see the AnyDesk Settings button, but no laptop picture.

I tried updating the AnyDesk software on the laptop, and reinstalling the app on the tablet.  I tried a second Windows 7 laptop with the same result.

Answer (score 5):

I've found this problem recently. I'm using Windows 10 on a HP Laptop with additional HDMI screen (the problem happend with or without the external screen).
After a Windows update the problem appeared, so I imagined the problem could be a corrupt configuration related with the screen or something.
I'm using the default HP Energy Plan (Recommended for HP), and fortunately I had another customized Energy plan with some parameters changed, and after changing it it worked fine.
Let me explain what is the parameter responsible of the black screen issue.

### Solution

1. Go to "**Energy Options**"
2. Go to "**Change the Plan Configuration**"
3. Go to "**Change Energy Advanced Configuration**"
4. Find parameters group "**Interchangeable Dynamic Graphics**"
5. The parameter "**Global Configuration**" is the PROBLEM.
   ___This parameter adjusted with "**Maximize performanc**e" works WRONG.
   ___This parameter adjusted with "**Optimized performance**" works FINE.

Comment: Thanks that realy helps!

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that if you connect to an active session if the target monitor shuts down you will see the screen in black as well.

It also happens for example if you connect by Anydesk to an RDP session and that RDP connection is closed.

The solution would be to log out, connect to anydesk and log in from the connection by Anydesk

Can it be what is happening to you?

Comment: if its black like  you mentioned it will be no mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening when an RDP session is minimized or you're signed out. To make anydesk available as a service you need to install it rather than running as exe. When you run it you'll be seeing an option "Install Anydesk"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little niche but in my case it was because I had colour correction turned on in accessibility settings (red/green colour-blind) on my tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a Chromebook, and turning off Night light under settings > Device > Displays resolved my issue. I knew it was a problem with chromebook because I could otherwise connect to anydesk from another client computer and also from my mobile. So watch out for color correction feature on different client machines!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, same thing happened to me, but I was just running AnyDesk.exe, it was not installed, and the user was logged out. After I installed it, absolutely no problem, I could enter the user account.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242750)

Comment: Ok, answering the question. Download from AnyDesk the AnyDesk.exe.Start the app, and close it. A question would appear, if you would like to install the app. Click yes, and you'll install the AnyDesk app. Then it will be much easier to control the remote desktop, and in this way you would resolve the Black Screen Problem for AnyDesk

Answer (score -1):

At least, it is my case.. :) another solution is using connecting by user account, then you put the user and password and you are in. I think it is also the case if more than one user is logged in the machine. Anythesk then doesn't know which desktop to connect.